# Numbered Index in Page Head

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, indexing

With the value "index=numbered" within the document class "scrbook" I changed the chapter head in this example from "MyIndex" to "2 MyIndex". In the pagehead there is still "MyIndex" printed instead of "2 MyIndex". How can I fix this when using Koma Script unless the markboth command does not help here.

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    twoside,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    listof=flat,
    headinclude,
    footinclude,
    index=numbered,
    usegeometry
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\upshape\sffamily\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\small}

\addto\captionsngerman{
    \def\indexname{MyIndex}%
    }
\makeindex
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyFirstPage}
Foo \index{foo}

Moo \index{moo}
\printindex%\markboth{Huhu}{Huhu} %this does not work here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO this is a bug. Maybe the KOMA-Script author has another opinion, but nevertheless you should report it.

Comment: Is done. Thx for the feedback. Harald

Comment: M. Kohm could reproduce this behavior and accepted the bug. Meanwhile it is fixed.

Comment: Link to the issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/52/